# Adding custom claims into AAD token

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible, while acquiring an access_token (Client Credentials grant), to instruct AAD to inject certain custom claims with certain values into the access_token being issued?

I need it to avoid sending extra context information to my service through such a "disconnected" means as HTTP Header for instance. Instead I want the token signed by AAD and containing everything AAD stamps into it by default plus some small pieces of information controlled by the application acquiring the token. All this will help my service to apply proper authorization once this token is received by the service.

Comment: Have you checked this [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2). Which explains how to add claims to a user during authentication.

Comment: The blog you pointed out shows how to add a claim into an instance of ClaimsIdentity, that is not what I asked about - I am looking for a way to add a claim into the token issued by AAD.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the above, and I am clear that you are not looking for claims augmentation as it was described in the blog.
As I understood, you are looking for the right way to authorized your application using AAD tokens.
If my understanding is correct here is my answer.

It took me quite sometime to remember how I did it before and the caveat was missing the graph permissions for:

```
  Directory.AccessAsUser.All
  Directory.Read.All
  Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

Now let me type down the steps one by one, but care less to the order of these steps may not be correct, just do the steps in any order you want.

**Step 1**: In AD, in the **App registration**
Register your Web Application,
Copy the Client_ID

**Step 2**: Go to **Expose an API**
Add a scope or more (This is what you are going to see as a claim and role in the token)
Add the client Client_ID

**Note**: this is basically for 2 applications one calling another, but in this example and your case, you have one web application that needs to authorize on itself.

**Next:** In the **API permissions**
When needed, grant admin consent delegated permissions for MicrosoftGraph

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

**Additionally**: Give permission to the *scope that you added*.

**Then**: In the **App roles**:
Add the Application roles

**Then**: In the **Enterprise Applications**:
Assign that role to the users or groups that you want to access this.

**Finally**: In the **application configuration file**
Update the Client id
You are done.
I hope that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Few months after my last answer, I see that Microsoft has a detailed documentation which does not require the Directory API permissions.
I know I was not able to receive the claims without them.
Maybe I was mistaken or changes occurred.
Here is the [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps):